# What is the solution to $y'(t)+g(t)=y^2(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> What is the solution to $y'(t)+g(t)=y^2(t)$?

This almost looks like a Bernoulli equation. If there was a $y$ in front of the $g$ it would be easy to solve. But what happens when there's no $y$ term? What substitution should we make then?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Assume you have a particular solution $ y_p$ then

$$y'-y_p'=(y-y_p)(y+y_p)$$

so if $ z=y-y_p $ then
$$z'=z(z+2y_p)$$
which is Bernoulli.

Comment: Sure, so you can solve for $z$ and then get $y=z+y_p$. How do you get $y_p$?

Comment: @user915952 It depends on $ g(t)$.

Comment: That is exactly my question, can you find a $y_p$ for general $g$?

Comment: @user915952 Surely no. If $ g(t)=\sqrt{cosh(t)} $ , no chance.